# compile with in "New Android Project" Always Empty

Tags: android

why compile with in "New Android Project" Always Empty ?

picture :

[image: Compile With Always Empty]

why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download one or more "SDK Platform" items from the SDK Manager, corresponding to the API levels you are interested in.

[image: SDK Manager, Showing "SDK Platform" for API Level 19]